# How to get details of running process in a computer using c# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, service

I am developing a windows service that store the details of current processes.
How do I get the **details of process running in system** and store that in a file using windows service using c# .NET.

I am trying to get all the information about a system(computer).

What are the files opened, which website is browsed etc. along with who is the current user.

Answer (score 1):

There are many aspects to a process, but you can get most of them off of the `System.Diagnostics.Process` object:

```
Process[] allProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
```

([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1f3ys1f9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

That will get you information on all running processes.

**However** much of the information you are looking for, such as what website is being browsed, simply *isn't available* to other processes. You could get *some* information about which files are open based on file-handles/locks, but even that will be somewhat limited.